# Does Z3 v4.3+ support quantifier elimination for NON-linear arithmetic

Tags: z3, nonlinear-functions, quantifiers

I could not find out what kind of quantifier elimination Z3 fully supports.
What I have is a universally quantified formula over -in general- non-linear terms. I would like to obtain an equivalent quantifier free formula. Is that possible with Z3?

Thanks,
Friedrich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Z3 has very limited support for quantifier elimination of nonlinear arithmetic. Moreover, it is not enabled by default. Here is an example on how to enable it, and demonstrating the limitations. It is also available online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/qqv1).

```
(set-option :pp-max-depth 20) ;; set option for Z3 pretty printer
(declare-const a Real)
(assert (exists ((x Real)) (= (* x x) a )))
(apply qe)
(echo "enabling nonlinear support...")
(apply (! qe :qe-nonlinear true))
;; It is very limited, it will fail in the following example
(echo "trying a cubic polynomial...")
(assert (exists ((x Real)) (= (* x x x) a)))
(apply (! qe :qe-nonlinear true))
```

Comment: Hi Leo, will qe support for nonlinear arithmetic be extended in the near future?

Comment: Not in the near future. Unless someone wants to work on that. BTW, we have all the machinery for implementing a quantifier elimination procedure based on CAD.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like a very interesting project to work on.