# Unbounded Infinite vs Bounded Infinite Domain for Universal Quantification over Reals in z3

Tags: z3, smt, z3py, quantifiers

This is a bit of a theoretical question. I was wondering if there's a difference in performance of z3 when solving universally quantified formulas over reals where the quantification is over a bounded infinite domain vs an unbounded infinite domain. I am working on something where I see that bounded infinite domains work much better in terms of performance and looking for a simple theoretical explanation for it. I am not able to find anything related in the literature, so any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner workings of most SMT solvers is black-box, where many heuristics/algorithms are in play. For arithmetic however, there are well-known techniques to deal with interesting fragments. I'd recommend reading through [https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-arithmetic](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Enikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-arithmetic), where they list what algorithms they use for each fragment.

Quantification is a totally different question. The usual approach is to apply quantifier elimination (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_elimination). z3 will perform quantifier elimination for linear-real arithmetic, but not for non-linear problems. See [Does Z3 v4.3+ support quantifier elimination for NON-linear arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056011/does-z3-v4-3-support-quantifier-elimination-for-non-linear-arithmetic), as the latter is a much more difficult problem and is not turned on by default.

Your particular case of putting bounds is an easy way to get rid of quantifiers, so it's not surprising that z3 might perform better. However, it's impossible to say without studying the internals if there are custom algorithms to take advantage of that. Your best bet is probably to ask at the z3 discussion forum, which I see you already have done: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/discussions/5949

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should add that I work with non-linear real arithmetic constraints. Do you think putting bounds in that case might help as well?

Comment: Sure; in fact it'd make quantifier elimination easier. When you have finite bounds, then what you really have is a finite conjunction of facts. (Without bounds, you have an infinite conjunction, which is the problematic bit.) Once quantifiers are gone, non-linear algorithms can kick in. (You might have to explicitly invoke the `nra` solver though, but it all depends on the internals.)

Comment: can you point me to a document or a paper where this procedure is detailed for the real arithmetic solver?

Comment: i should also clarify that when I say bounded infinite, i mean an interval like [0, 1] compared to unbounded infinite which is [-inf, +inf].

Comment: I'm not aware of any papers; probably simple folklore. To prove `forall x. 0 < x < 1. F(x)`, you'd negate it to get `exists x. 0 < x < 1. Not(F(x))`, which can now be lifted to the top-level existential `x` with the extra constraints; getting rid of the quantifiers. Of course it all depends on what your actual `F` looks like. It's much more complicated when you have nested/alternating quantifiers.