# Searching Skolem functions in non-linear arithmetics

Tags: z3, smt, quantifiers, first-order-logic

I found that the following paper/code (https://github.com/grigoryfedyukovich/aeval) solves Skolem function search for linear arithmetic. It performs really well.

However, I would like to compute Skolem functions for non-linear arithmetic. Does anyone know any tool for this? For instance, given `Forall x. Exists y. (x^2<y)` should return `f(x)=x^2+1`.

I know Z3 is not the best for such queries, but do you know any method in the state of the art for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this answer from 2013 is still the state of affairs, so far as z3 is concerned: [Does Z3 v4.3+ support quantifier elimination for NON-linear arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056011/does-z3-v4-3-support-quantifier-elimination-for-non-linear-arithmetic/16064548#16064548)

Also see https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/6790. So, the answer is negative: z3 does not do quantifier elimination for non-linear arithmetic.

Comment: And do you know any other tool suitable for this?

Comment: https://www.usna.edu/CS/qepcadweb/B/QEPCAD.html perhaps? I'm not familiar with it though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It surprisingly seems like a problem that has not been so much studied. I am amazed, since non-linear real arithmetic is a decidable theory.